# PHP - Get URL of a file from its path stored in different folder

Tags: php, yii

I have a project in YII framework where I want static content sharable to different sites. Let's assume I have a folder `common` where I stored all images and documents in localhost ie `var/www/html` folder. Now I have two other folders in localhost ie `site1` and `site2`. Now I want to use static content of `common` folder in both `site1` and `site2`. I am not able to generate absolute URL of image files. I am using below function to get URL from the file path and it is not working with the current scenario. I really appreciate your help.

`function FilePath2URL($file, $Protocol='http://', $addHost= false) {
    $host = $addHost ? $Protocol."".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']: "";
    if(strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS,0,3))==='WIN'){
        $file_p=str_replace('\\','/',$file);
        $file_p=str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'],'',$file_p);
        $url= self::websiteDomain().DS.$file_p;
    }
    else {
        $url = $host.str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], '', $file);
    }
    return file_exists($file)?$url."?".filemtime($file):$url; }`

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In general you cannot have a URL pointing to a folder that is external to the site's root. If your server runs in Linux, you should define a symbolic link (ln command) to your common folder into the site1 and site2 folder, for instance:

```
ln -s /var/html/common /var/html/site1/common
ln -s /var/html/common /var/html/site2/common
```

so that the real "common" folder is seen through a virtual "common" subfolder of the site. Doing that you probably need to manage permissions to allow the site's program to read the real "common" folder that is external to the site root (with Apache, adjusting the SELinux permissions [if SELinux is active] and php open_basedir restrictions, if your site is running php).